# What is the purpose of pointer rebind?

Tags: c++, pointers, traits

I trying to implement `std::list` (MSVC). And one thing I cannot understand:

```
template <class _Value_type, class _Voidptr> // voidptr? For what?
struct _List_node { // list node
    using value_type = _Value_type;
    using _Nodeptr   = _Rebind_pointer_t<_Voidptr, _List_node>; // what is the purpose of such rebind?
    ...
}
```

I understand the reason of allocator rebind, but pointer? Why should I use it and where?

UPD: I understand, what rebind is. I mean, why not just `_Nodeptr*`? Why do I need rebind? (Thanks to Evg)

Comment: Related: http://blog.nuggetwheat.org/index.php/2015/09/01/why-pointer_traits-was-introduced-in-c11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question comes from allocators, too. Let's take a look at how `_Rebind_pointer_t` is [defined](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/xmemory#L243):

```
template <class _Ptr, class _Ty>
using _Rebind_pointer_t = typename pointer_traits<_Ptr>::template rebind<_Ty>;
```

That is, we have

```
template <class _Value_type, class _Voidptr>
struct _List_node {
    using _Nodeptr = typename pointer_traits<_Voidptr>::template rebind<_List_node>;
    // ...
}
```

Now let's take a look at how `_List_node` is [used](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/list#L772):

```
using _Node = _List_node<_Ty, typename _Alty_traits::void_pointer>;
```

Effectively, we rebind allocator's `void_pointer` to `_List_node` pointer. This trick is needed to support allocators that use fancy pointers internally.

---

One such example can be found in Boost.Interprocess library. It has [boost::interprocess::allocator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/allocator.html):

> An STL compatible allocator that uses a segment manager as memory source. The internal pointer type will of the same type (raw, smart) as `typename SegmentManager::void_pointer` type. This allows placing the allocator in shared memory, memory mapped-files, etc...

For example, we can write

```
namespace bi = boost::interprocess;
using Allocator = bi::allocator<int, bi::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
std::list<int, Allocator> list(/* allocator object */);
```

Now `std::allocator_traits<decltype(list)::allocator_type>::void_pointer` will be not `void*` as with default allocator, but `boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, ...>`. As a result, `_Nodeptr` will be not `_Nodeptr*`, but `boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<_Nodeptr, ...>`.

Comment: Thank you. You are helped to understand previous answer)

Answer (score 1):

The user instantiates the list with the `value_type.`
For example for `list<int>` the `value_type` would be `int`.
Also the list allocator (which can also be provided)  allocates memory for objects of `value_type`'s.

But the `value_type` **is not** what the list internally holds.
The list holds internally the `**Nodes**` for which the value_type is a member of.

So to be able to convert allocation and pointer's from `value_type` to `Node` (which holds value_type and pointer to the next node at least) the rebind is used.

In contrary, this would not be need for a `vector<int>` for example.
That's because the internal representation of vector will normaly hold internally the pointer to array of value_type's objects and that's int in this case. So no rebind needed here.

Comment: The real question is: why not just `_Nodeptr*`? Why do you need rebind?

Comment: Yeap, I need to specify the question

Comment: @Evg: Because no one says what the pointer really is. It can just be Node* but could theoretically also be some kind of fancy pointer. So basically: I want the Node to be the same kind of poitner as value_type, no matter what kind of pointer it is.

Comment: @StPiere, well, now I understand the idea. Can you write the example, please? (link or smth))

Comment: @Shamil: you already wrote the example yourself. Just look at some implementation of list stl: msvc, libstdc++ etc. For kind of fancy pointer you can google for and look at for example: boost::interprocess::offset_ptr